# post a csv file to url

Tags: r, csv, post

I am trying to post a .csv file to a url and it works when I am using Python with this code :

```
import requests
url = 'http:...'
files = {'file': open('test.csv')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Since all the other code is in R and I would like to have all the code at one place I tried to translate it. I tried several different things:

```
library(httr)

POST("http:...",
     body = list(name = "test.csv", 
     filedata = upload_file("~/test.csv", "text/csv")))

POST("http:...",
     body = list(testFile = "~/test.csv"))

POST("http:...", 
     body = upload_file("~/test.csv"))
```

But I keep on running into the same error.

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    Timeout
>   was reached

Is there any other way I could try to upload the file to the url using R?
Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: have you tried setting the proxy with `use_proxy(...)` inside `POST()` ?